# ndk-stack Error (3): No such process

Tags: android, android-ndk, stack, crash-dumps

I'm having problem with my library that I successfully compiled to be debugged on NDK.

My application crashes and exists abnormally so I wanted to search why this is happening.

I found ndk-stack can be a way to understand where it crashes so first read documentation of ndk-stack and then 
tried to apply ndk-stack method on my library.

But when I try to run ndk-stack on cygwin as follows it gives "No such process" error.

Anybody knows why this happens?

Thank you.

```
$ ./ndk-stack -sym data/data/com.project.myproject/lib -dump ../logcat.txt
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'Huawei/U8650/hwu8650:2.3.3/HuaweiU8650/C00B824_NFCFW:user/release-                keys'
pid: 16976, tid: 16989  >>> com.project.myproject <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr fffffffb
Stack frame #00  pc 810cd3b0  /data/data/com.project.myproject/lib/libndk_databases.so:     Unable to open symbol file data/da
ta/com.project.myproject/lib/libndk_databases.so. Error (3): No such process
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value for -sym argument should be local directory on your disk for obj/local/armeabi folder that contains libndk_databases.so file.